# вывод данных из нескольких таблиц сразу

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Имеется несколько таблиц, с данными пользователя. В первой его основные данные, во второй его телефоны, в третьей его майлы, в четвёртой контактные данные и в пятой данные о работе. В основном view под каждым контактом есть кнопка, в атрибуте которой(data-value) записан id `<a href="#" id="edit-contact-modal" data-value="<?=$contact['contid']?>" class="btn btn-purple entity-btn-params waves-effect waves-light btn-xs m-b-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-contact-win">Редактировать</a>`. В каждой из таблиц есть поле contid, которое является общим для всех. Нужно вывести связанные между собой данные в одно общее модальное окно, с учётом того, что телефонов и майлов может быть несколько, а значит и поля должны автоматически формироваться, но пока что я не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Для каждой таблицы, содержащей мультиатрибуты, выполнить `GROUP BY` по юзеру и `GROUP_CONCAT` по мультиатрибуту. Такие подзапросы и остальные таблицы с атрибутами связать (`INNER` либо `LEFT JOIN`) с основной таблицей и вывести все данные в нужном формате с нужными именами полей.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте команду JOIN, а именно INNER JOIN для Вас. В одном запросе можно объединить сколько угодно таблиц.

Comment: В одной таблице два телефона. В другой два мыла. Итог - 4 записи... вот автору явно не оно надо. Равно как и не надо пропустить ретрограда, в принципе не пользующегося электронной почтой.